# Burninate [tags] and [tagging] tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request, burninate-request

[tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) are used for too many things:

- VCS tags
- tags in view of MVC paradigm in various frameworks
- HTML tags

I think they should be blacklisted and existing questions should be re-tagged with more specific tags.

Comment: What harm are these tags causing?

Comment: There's only 3000 of one and 300 of another.  Get editing.  The ASP folks did it for the `asp` tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought any tag that has too many meanings should be burninated and blacklisted

Comment: @AndreyBotalov: That's something that the community has cooked up.  It's probably not wrong, but sometimes I think it's carried to an extreme.  If the tag needs further clarification, you can always pair it with another tag like [html] during a search.

Comment: One definition of a meta tag is that it means different things to different people.  These fit that definition, in that they require additional context to have a meaning.  However, they *should not* be blindly burninated, because doing so may harm the questions.  This is going to have to be a one-by-one mass retag, as casperOne suggested.  That said, these tags aren't *that* bad.

Comment: @casperOne Do you mean that burninating and blacklisting will be only after questions will be retagged?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov It was partially tongue-in-cheek.  But, for a tag with 300 questions, that's something that can be manually done (in about 1/2 hour).  For 3K, considerably longer.  The thing is, you need to find out what tags really *should* be applied, not just remove the tags.  Blacklisting only comes in extreme circumstances.  This might be one of them, but it's hard to say.